# Creating a src/main/java folder structure in Eclipse without Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications

How do I create the `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` in my default web application project in Eclipse without Maven? My current folder structure is

```
TestApp
├── JavaResources
│   └── src  
│       └── com.mypackage
└── WebContent
```

Comment: Just add a source folder.

Comment: You can create them yourself like a regular folders. Create src folder, than test inside src then java inside test

Comment: I am unable to add sub folders to src folder in eclipse. Can you please let me know how I can do that ?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

As you've discovered, you can't have a source folder inside another source folder, so before you can create `src/main/java` you have to tell Eclipse not to treat `src` as a source folder.  To do this, right click on the `src` folder and select build path -> remove from build path.

Once you have done this `src` will appear in the folder tree in its normal place, so you can create the `main` and `java` folders under it, and move the existing `src/com` to `src/main/java/com`.  Finally right-click the newly-created `java` folder and select build path -> use as source folder.

Comment: After selecting use as source folder option, the structure of folder is created but while updating the maven project it is giving error : Unable to update maven configuration for the following projects. Cannot nest 'Foldername/src/main/java' inside 'Foldername/src'. To enable the nesting exclude 'main/' from 'SelectExample/src'

Answer (score 12):

I have solved this issue by below steps:

Right click the Maven Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
In Order and Export tab, you can see the message like '2 build path entries are missing'
Now select 'JRE System Library' and 'Maven Dependencies' checkbox
Click OK

Answer (score 6):

Open  `Properties > Java Build Path` for the project. Select the `Source` tab and use `Add Folders` to add source folders.

Comment: Thanks for replying but when I try to add sub folders I am getting and error msg . "Cannot nest 'TestApp/src/main/java exclude 'main/' from 'TestApp/src"

Comment: You simply cannot have `src` and `src/main` both as a source folder by default. But you can exclude `main` from `src` in `Source` tab (my Eclipse version did it by default)...

Comment: Can you explain me how I can exclude it ?

Comment: Remove the existing src entry and then add the new entries

Answer (score 2):

Remove the actual source folder definition in the build path and add a new source folder an name it `src/main/java`

Comment: I tried to edit and rename the folder structure but I am getting the following error.An internal error occurred during: "Setting build path".
assertion failed: Cannot move '/TestApp/src'. Destination should not be under source's hierarchy.

Comment: Do not edit it! just delete it and create a new one!

Comment: I already have some packages under src folder and I don't want to lose it. Nvm I was able to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the package structure is setup as `src.main.java.com.inventica`, instead of `com.inventica`, that’s usually because under project properties > Java build path > Source, the source folder is setup as `src` instead of `src/main/java`. There’s no easy way to fix this, so remove `src` as a source folder and click ok.

Now Eclipse will show a folder hierarchy `src/main/java`. Browse to the `java` folder > right-click > build path > use as source folder.

After this, you may have to fix the Eclipse .project and .classpath files to have it use Maven to manage dependencies, builds etc.

Typically, you can copy this from a working project since there isn’t anything project specific here assuming you’re structured as a standard Maven project.

Answer (score 1):

the problem will be solved by checking on 'JRE System Library' and 'Maven Dependencies' checkboxs Click OK. this is found in the project's 'build path option'

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you don't find the Included Path just add the path it will resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Solution One:

Change the JRE version to 1.8 and change it back to the original version (for maven-archetype-webapp, the original version is 1.7).

[image: Steps Here]

Solution Two:

Check the JRE option and Maven Dependencies option in "Order and Export".

[image: Steps Here]

Answer (score 1):

Open Properties > Java Build Path for the project. Select the Source tab and use Add Folders to add source folders.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be create 'java' folder directly one the drive into src/main even before opening it in eclipse that way eclipse will not complain about the issue.