# Eclipse confuses source folders with package folders

Tags: java, eclipse

I want the structure of my project to look like this (It is a maven project) in Eclipse:

[image]

I don't want to put the image of how it looks like, because it contains package names that can give away things internal to the company.  At any rate, I have those four folders, but instead of folders they are packages.

So, to eclipse my project contains a src folder (that has the same icon as the icon of the four folders of the picture above), and that folder contains four packages:

- main.resources
- test.resources
- main.java.com.somethingelse
- main.java.com.somethingelse

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the folder structure on the disk doesn't look like this /src/main/java/main/java/com/somethingelse ?

Comment: It sounds like Eclipse thinks that `src` is the source folder, rather than `src/main/java` - see [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22915508/592139) for an explanation of how to clean this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the drop-down arrow menu in the Package Explorer View, try changing Package Presentation from Flat to Hierarchical.

I find this setting to be more helpful than the default. I am not sure whether that addresses your concern... it's not clear to me from the question what you are expecting your package layout to look like.