# Not able to acess package private methods in junit test class

Tags: java, methods, junit, visibility

So right now I have the following standard package name setup in my project:

- src/main/java/model/SampleClass.java
  which you can view @ https://github.com/quinnliu/WalnutiQ/blob/master/src/main/java/model/SampleClass.java
- src/test/java/model/SampleClassTest.java
  which you can view @ https://github.com/quinnliu/WalnutiQ/blob/master/src/test/java/model/SampleClassTest.java

SampleClass.java looks like this:

```
package main.java.model;

public class SampleClass {
    int packagePrivateMethod() {
    return -1;
    }
}
```

And SampleClassTest.java looks like this:

```
package test.java.model;

import main.java.model.SampleClass;

public class SampleClassTest extends junit.framework.TestCase {
    private SampleClass sampleClass;

    public void setUp() {
    this.sampleClass = new SampleClass();
    }

    public void test_packagePrivateMethod() {
    // this method can't be called right now why?
    //this.sampleClass.packagePrivateMethod();
    }
}
```

Why can't the method packagePrivateMethod() be called???

Comment: its not private. It has default access.

Comment: You do know that *package private* (default) access means that only other classes in the same package can access it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't be called because the two classes are not in the same package. One is in `main.java.model` the other in `test.java.model`.

Comment: But what about the best answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004710/what-is-the-advantage-of-the-src-main-java-convention

Comment: In this answer (i.e. a conventional maven project setup), two source folders are used `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`. The two classes are therefore in the same package (in this case the root or default package).