# Loading properties on Spring Boot test classes

Tags: java, spring-boot

My Spring Boot project structure is the following:
[image]

I have my tests code in the Main class under `src/test`, and a test-dedicated properties file under `scr/test/resources`
I would like to load that file so that i can read its properties from my Main (test) java class, so i do (in the Main class):
[image]

But the file is not loaded, at least i assume so, because when i try to read a property in this way:
`@Value("${some.property.present.in.that.file}")
 private String prop;`
 
then `prop` is always null.
I dont understand why this mechanism works in my `src/main/java`code but not under test, the ApplicationContext should be there, the Main test class is annotated with `@SpringBootTest` which as you can see targets to itself, and the  [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) says:
[image]

Any advice about this?

Comment: try `@TestPropertySource(locations= "classpath:test/application-test.properties)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that if you move your tests to src/test/java/* the SpringBootTest will see them without any other configs.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html#using-boot-structuring-your-code it says that it does not need a specific layout to work

Comment: You were right, i refactored my code and magically now it works, its a bit confusing though that they say that Spring Boot will work regardless of the project structure, thx!

Comment: @JBoy
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004710/what-is-the-advantage-of-the-src-main-java-convention