# Swagger-codegen-maven: Change where files are generated to

Tags: swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I'm currently using swagger-codegen through the maven plugin: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin.
I've set the place where I want my api files to be generated with the `<apiPackage></apiPackage>` field in my pom.xml.
But when I generate my apis, it gets put in `src/main/java/<apiPackage>`. I would like to know where is `src/main/java` declared as part of the path and if it can be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`src/main/java` is a [Maven convention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3004710/113116).

This folder structure is [hard-coded](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages/AbstractJavaCodegen.java#L78-L81) in Swagger Codegen's code and cannot be changed.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend AbstractJavaCodegen and in constructor override  value of sourceFolder variable. This extended class you can passed to codegen as --lang parameter.